# Coding a robot to change direction about the same point

Tags: c++, generics, robotics

I'm trying to code a robot in a 2D cartesian system with two commands 
L = Move 1 unit in the direction it's facing 
H = Change its direction by an angle θ counterclockwise  **but stays at the same point** 

The robot starts at origin (0,0) and is facing the positive x axis

```
The string of commands will be read from left to right
```

Example

```
 LHLH = Move 1 Unit in Positive X axis 
        Rotate to an angle θ counterclockwise
        Move 1 unit in the direction it faces after rotating angle θ counterclockwise
        Rotate to angle θ counterclockwise again
```

I want to determine that if there are certain angles θ for which the Robot can never return to origin, and if there are certain angles for which it inevitably always reaches origin.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should navigate the whole plane. If the angle is in range [0, 360] you are always able to find only one direction for each angle.

So you can always return to origin, with different combinations of rotations and movements.

Comment: While that does seem intuitive, do you have any way of proving it?